# Why is my credit score now being ranked on a scale of 501 to 990?

Tags: credit-score, credit-report, credit, fico-score

Over the years, I've run several credit reports on myself inching my way closer to 750 then 800 on a FICO scale. Then, using [TrueCredit](http://www.truecredit.com) to analyze my report, as I always have, I suddenly notice I'm being graded now on a scale of 501 to 990.

What's worse is that I was in the 90th percentile of average US scores on the FICO scale. Now I'm as low as the 59th percentile with one of the reporting bureaus! And I didn't even do anything wrong financially this last year!

I assume this is not a FICO score, but instead the grading standards have changed? What is this new number, and how can I improve it now? I was so close to 800 before...

Comment: I feel dirty after clicking on the TrueCredit link.   When I went to close my browser it popped up saying Hey, a live representative wants to chat with you about this opportunity.    Smells very scammy.

Comment: @AlexB: Eh, they're alright. They've given me accurate information and they're fairly cheap. But I know what you mean - going through the process of cancelling your account with them is very scammy. They just keep giving you reasons to stay with them. I have to do that every couple months after I get the report I need and don't need to check again for a while.

Comment: Sadly, truecredit is run by TransUnion, which means in the credit score/report business you don't get much less scammy. That was very annoying to me as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIRC it's not a FICO score, as mentioned [here](http://consumers.creditnet.com/Discussions/credit-talk/t-truecredit-credit-scores-new-score-71182.html), too.

That said, apart from borrowing money to optimise your credit score as a hobby, my understanding is that once you're above a FICO score of 750, it pretty much doesn't matter how close to 800 you get.

Comment: Wow that question pretty much mirrors mine. So in summary, as long as I have a decent FICO over 750, nothing else matters, correct? Is myFICO.com the only place to get your true FICO score? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NoCatharsis - always, always, always use the bureaus from annualcreditreport.com.  They give you your report free and the score they provide for a few added dollars.  annualcreditreport.com is the safe and approved way to get to the bureaus who make up your FICO score.

Comment: Got it. But then what about myFICO.com as discussed here? Is that not the same agency?

Comment: You should worry about negative items on your credit report. The only time you need your score is before you buy a car or house.